# Can't find com.google.api.client.ByteStrams

Tags: google-api-client

Simple question: I can't find this class in com.google.api.client.util (where it should be).

I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/api/client/util/ByteStreams
```

But I have that package and it isn't there. More precisely, I have google-api-client-util-1.2.3-alpha.jar and it isn't there.
[image: So as you can see, it isn't there]

So as you can see, it isn't there.
And I have older versions too but it isn't there niether.

Answer (score 0):

The class I was looking for is in google-http-client package.